# Parent Child Path hierarchy in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, recursion, parent-child, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to get child parent hierarchy in new pandas column. Currently my code looks like this, but it search for all parents, but it should search for the one in corresponding row.

Here is the example how it should work.

Base table (input):

| CHILD_ID | PARENT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| ITEM_1 | ITEM_A |
| ITEM_2 | ITEM_B |
| ITEM_A | ITEM_X |
| ITEM_A | ITEM_Y |
| ITEM_B | ITEM_Z |

First iteration

| CHILD_ID | PARENT_ID | Hierarchy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ITEM_1 | ITEM_A | ITEM_1, ITEM_A |
| ITEM_2 | ITEM_B | ITEM_2, ITEM_B |
| ITEM_A | ITEM_X | ITEM_A, ITEM_X |
| ITEM_A | ITEM_Y | ITEM_A, ITEM_Y |
| ITEM_B | ITEM_Z | ITEM_B, ITEM_Z |

Second iteration (in this case desired output as there is no more parents)

| CHILD_ID | PARENT_ID | Hierarchy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ITEM_1 | ITEM_A | ITEM_1, ITEM_A, ITEM_X |
| ITEM_1 | ITEM_A | ITEM_1, ITEM_A, ITEM_Y |
| ITEM_2 | ITEM_B | ITEM_2, ITEM_B, ITEM_Z |
| ITEM_A | ITEM_X | ITEM_A, ITEM_X |
| ITEM_A | ITEM_Y | ITEM_A, ITEM_Y |
| ITEM_B | ITEM_Z | ITEM_B, ITEM_Z |

I'm struggling to achieve this result, here's my code:

```py
def get_parents(child_id):
    list_of_parents = []

    def dfs(child_id, parents_list):
        parent_ids = df[df["child_id"] == child_id]["parent_id"].values
        if len(parent_ids) == 0:
            return
        for parent_id in parent_ids:
            if parent_id not in parents_list:
                parents_list.append(parent_id)
                dfs(parent_id, parents_list)

    dfs(child_id, list_of_parents)
    return list_of_parents

df["parent_hierarchy"] = df["child_id"].apply(get_parents)
```

example problem:

When trying to run the code on whole dataframe this error ocurrs:
NetworkXNoPath: No path between 4614837_12_13200 and 4975995_5_13200.

After filtering dataframe to only those ID's in both sides, code worked but still doesnt work for the input dataframe

| parent_id | child_id |
| --- | --- |
| 4975995_5_13200 | 4789551_5_13200 |
| 5003373_3_13200 | 4614837_12_13200 |
| 4975995_5_13200 | 4602153_19_13200 |
| 4975995_5_13200 | 4789551_7_13200 |
| 4974894_5_13200 | 4614837_12_13200 |
| 4975995_5_13200 | 4789551_10_13200 |
| 4975995_5_13200 | 4789551_3_13200 |
| 4975995_5_13200 | 4789551_6_13200 |
| 4975995_5_13200 | 4789551_2_13200 |

SQL Code that was used in draft but the will be finally in Python.

```sql
SELECT
CONCAT_WS(
  "|", 
  concat(
    bl1.parent_item_id 
  ), 
  IF(
    bl2.parent_item_id IS NULL, 
    NULL, 
    concat(
      bl2.parent_item_id 
    )
  ), 
  IF(
    bl3.parent_item_id IS NULL, 
    NULL, 
    concat(
      bl3.parent_item_id 
    )
  ), 
  IF(
    bl4.parent_item_id IS NULL, 
    NULL, 
    concat(
      bl4.parent_item_id 
    )
  ), 
  IF(
    bl5.parent_item_id IS NULL, 
    NULL, 
    concat(
      bl5.parent_item_id 
    )
  ), 
  IF(
    bl6.parent_item_id IS NULL, 
    NULL, 
    concat(
      bl6.parent_item_id 
    )
  ), 
  IF(
    bl7.parent_item_id IS NULL, 
    NULL, 
    concat(
      bl7.parent_item_id 
    )
  ), 
  IF(
    bl8.parent_item_id IS NULL, 
    NULL, 
    concat(
      bl8.parent_item_id 
    )
  ), 
  IF(
    bl9.parent_item_id IS NULL, 
    NULL, 
    concat(
      bl9.parent_item_id 
    )
  ), 
  IF(
    bl10.parent_item_id IS NULL, 
    NULL, 
    concat(
      bl10.parent_item_id 
    )
  )
) AS PATH -- joins to find 10 levels of items
FROM 
  baseln AS bl1 
  LEFT JOIN baseln AS bl2 ON bl1.parent_item_id = bl2.child_item_id 
  AND bl1.child_item_id IS NOT NULL 
  LEFT JOIN baseln AS bl3 ON bl2.parent_item_id = bl3.child_item_id 
  AND bl2.child_item_id IS NOT NULL 
  LEFT JOIN baseln AS bl4 ON bl2.parent_item_id = bl4.child_item_id 
  AND bl3.child_item_id IS NOT NULL 
  LEFT JOIN baseln AS bl5 ON bl2.parent_item_id = bl5.child_item_id 
  AND bl4.child_item_id IS NOT NULL 
  LEFT JOIN baseln AS bl6 ON bl2.parent_item_id = bl6.child_item_id 
  AND bl5.child_item_id IS NOT NULL 
  LEFT JOIN baseln AS bl7 ON bl2.parent_item_id = bl7.child_item_id 
  AND bl6.child_item_id IS NOT NULL 
  LEFT JOIN baseln AS bl8 ON bl2.parent_item_id = bl8.child_item_id 
  AND bl7.child_item_id IS NOT NULL 
  LEFT JOIN baseln AS bl9 ON bl2.parent_item_id = bl9.child_item_id 
  AND bl8.child_item_id IS NOT NULL 
  LEFT JOIN baseln AS bl10 ON bl2.parent_item_id = bl10.child_item_id 
  AND bl9.child_item_id IS NOT NULL
```

NetworkX does throw an error with below dataframe

```
{'parent_id':['4974894_5_13200','5003373_3_13200','4974894_5_13200','4974894_5_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','4974894_5_13200','4974894_5_13200','5003373_3_13200','4974894_5_13200','4974894_5_13200','5003373_3_13200','4974894_5_13200','4974894_5_13200','4974894_5_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','4974894_5_13200','5003373_3_13200','4975995_5_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','4974894_5_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','4974894_5_13200','4975995_5_13200','4974894_5_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','4974894_5_13200','4974894_5_13200','4975995_5_13200','5003373_3_13200','4974894_5_13200','4974894_5_13200','5003373_3_13200','4974894_5_13200','4974894_5_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','4974894_5_13200','4974894_5_13200','4974894_5_13200','5003373_3_13200','4975995_5_13200','5003373_3_13200','4974894_5_13200','5003373_3_13200','4974894_5_13200','4975995_5_13200','5003373_3_13200','4974894_5_13200','4974894_5_13200','5003373_3_13200','4975995_5_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','4974894_5_13200','4975995_5_13200','5003373_3_13200','4974894_5_13200','4974894_5_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200','5003373_3_13200'],'child_id':['4602363_15_13200','4613145_13_13200','4602528_21_13200','4613145_11_13200','4614837_8_13200','4613145_11_13200','4613370_11_13200','4595322_17_13200','4602576_18_13200','4595310_14_13200','4595310_14_13200','4602528_23_13200','4602528_22_13200','4595322_16_13200','4595310_13_13200','4602384_16_13200','4602153_18_13200','4602384_17_13200','4602576_17_13200','4602528_18_13200','4789551_5_13200','4613046_18_13200','4602576_17_13200','4595310_9_13200','4602363_10_13200','4595322_16_13200','4602528_21_13200','4602171_17_13200','4602153_18_13200','4602153_12_13200','4595322_17_13200','4602576_12_13200','4613145_9_13200','4602576_11_13200','4602363_15_13200','4602171_12_13200','4602528_15_13200','4613370_15_13200','4614837_12_13200','4613370_14_13200','4602363_16_13200','4595322_11_13200','4595322_10_13200','4613370_15_13200','4602153_19_13200','4614837_11_13200','4613046_13_13200','4602384_10_13200','4602363_16_13200','4613370_14_13200','4789551_7_13200','4602171_10_13200','4595322_13_13200','4613046_18_13200','4602363_14_13200','4614837_12_13200','4602384_17_13200','4602576_16_13200','4613370_16_13200','4602528_18_13200','4602528_22_13200','4613145_14_13200','4602384_16_13200','4789551_10_13200','4602528_23_13200','4613046_17_13200','4602153_19_13200','4602363_14_13200','4789551_3_13200','4595310_13_13200','4602153_19_13200','4613370_16_13200','4602363_9_13200','4789551_6_13200','4602576_18_13200','4613145_14_13200','4595322_13_13200','4602384_13_13200','4602576_16_13200','4789551_2_13200','4614837_11_13200','4613145_13_13200','4602171_17_13200','4613046_17_13200','4614837_7_13200','4602153_11_13200']}
```

Comment: The input and expected output are unclear. Do you need all iterations or just the final state?

Comment: @mozway I have edited the input. Now it should be clear

Comment: Not fully, you didn't say if you want the last step or all intermediates

Comment: @mozway okay, so I want the last step as my output. I only presented the first iteration as a "process demo" my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/) to create the hierarchy:

```
import networkx as nx

# create graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, create_using=nx.DiGraph,
                            source='CHILD_ID', target='PARENT_ID')

out = {}
# for each subgraph, form pairs of nodes -> leaf
# find the path
for c in nx.weakly_connected_components(G):
    H = G.subgraph(c)
    leaves = {n for n, d in H.out_degree() if d==0}
    for n in c-leaves:
        for l in leaves:
            try:
                out.setdefault(n, []).append(nx.shortest_path(H, n, l))
            except nx.NetworkXNoPath:
                pass

# merge to unique CHILD_ID
# recreate PARENT_ID
# reorder based on original DataFrame
out = df.merge(df[['CHILD_ID']].drop_duplicates()
                 .merge(pd.Series(out, name='Hierarchy').explode(),
                        left_on='CHILD_ID', right_index=True)
                 .assign(PARENT_ID=lambda d: d['Hierarchy'].str[1]),
               how='left')
```

Output:

```
  CHILD_ID PARENT_ID                 Hierarchy
0   ITEM_1    ITEM_A  [ITEM_1, ITEM_A, ITEM_X]
1   ITEM_1    ITEM_A  [ITEM_1, ITEM_A, ITEM_Y]
2   ITEM_2    ITEM_B  [ITEM_2, ITEM_B, ITEM_Z]
3   ITEM_A    ITEM_X          [ITEM_A, ITEM_X]
4   ITEM_A    ITEM_Y          [ITEM_A, ITEM_Y]
5   ITEM_B    ITEM_Z          [ITEM_B, ITEM_Z]
```

Graph:

[image]

Comment: I've encountered this error, is this due to bad data quality? I cannot check the whole dataset. 

NetworkXNoPath: No path between 4602576_16_13200 and 4975995_5_13200.

Comment: No, then the code needs to be adapted. Can you update your example to reproduce this error?

Comment: I have updated question with problematic example.

Comment: This example [works fine for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuzQ3.png)

Comment: Yes indeed, its very strange because with the whole dataframe I got following error: NetworkXNoPath: No path between 4614837_12_13200 and 4975995_5_13200. When I filter the whole df to contain only those id's in both (parent/child) combinations it works, but doesnt for the whole dataframe.

Comment: That's why I asked if you could generate a small subset of the DataFrame that produces this error (maybe sample a few rows randomly, if you get an error then export the reproducible df with `df.to_dict('list')`)

Comment: I've added df example as suggested

Comment: @Rafał so this one triggers an error? For me it [also works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCenG.png). Which python/pandas/networkx versions did you use?

Comment: Yeah, the dictionary that I have  pasted in my question is triggering that error.
NetworkXNoPath: No path between 4602384_10_13200 and 4975995_5_13200. Python version: 3.11.4 NetworkX version: 3.1 Pandas version: 2.0.3

Comment: @Rafał got it, I hadn't seen the dictionary I used the short table. I can indeed reproduce and as I thought this happens when you have hierarchies with potentially multiple parents, a simple try/except should do the trick since we can ignore the cases in which no path exist

Answer (score -2):

usw a combination of dataframe operations and a recursive function.
here's a new code, you should be able to implement this after you load the data

```
def get_hierarchy(child_id, hierarchy=[]):
    hierarchy.append(child_id)
    parent_id = df.loc[df["CHILD_ID"] == child_id, "PARENT_ID"].values
    if len(parent_id) > 0:
        get_hierarchy(parent_id[0], hierarchy)
    return hierarchy

df["Hierarchy"] = df["CHILD_ID"].apply(get_hierarchy)
```

Comment: Is this an AI generated answer? This doesn't seem to work

Comment: Watch out for the [`hierarchy=[]` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).